# FBML-Support with Facebook C# SDK 5.0.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

**How can i add FBML-Support with Facebook C# SDK 5.0.3, to my ASP.NET Facebook App 
(like a TagPrefix)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/241261 it's not supported.